# Porting from Eclipse and Upgrading Android Libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I have an Android application that we have been building in Eclipse for years, and I am finally porting it to Android Studio (I am new to Android Studio and Gradle, so forgive my ignorance). I have successfully ported it and the app is up and running in Android Studio, but now need to overcome a couple more obstacles:

1. I want to upgrade deprecated methods and also move to the latest versions of Support Library, Google Services and GSon (I guess I can live without upgrading GSon if need be).
2. To complicate matters, we have an Ant based build which takes the source code and generates numerous white label instances of application, with some pretty complex replacements. I plan on keeping that - I don't want to Gradle that just yet (and not sure Gradle could handle it?).

So, first it looks like my Gradle generated by the port has dependencies as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        [....other dependencies that don't matter here....]
    }
```

My question is : do I still need to have the upgraded versions of these libs here or is this done via a Gradle addition for running out Android Studio? And if not by lib dependencies as listed, how can I have the Ant build pick these upgrades once I make them? I do have a further complexity in that I think the generated source code structure is different than Eclipse, but I think I can adjust the Ant build accordingly.

I have read these, and while helpful really don't quite answer my question:

[Android white labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828970/android-white-labeling)

and

[Android App White Labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701600/android-app-white-labeling)

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

So after a LOT of playing around I finally have upgraded modules and libraries and it apparently (I need to do a lot of testing) is working. Not sure if this will save anyone anytime in the future, but the key seems to be:

1. Match the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion versions.
2. Match the com.android.support:support and compile and tools versions, as closely as possible.
3. For the Support lib, choose the version just below your minSDK version (in my case it is 14, so I chose v13). I might have it wrong there but that is what got it working for me.
4. Be careful in which modules and which version of the modules you bring in, and that they are compatible. The tool did a decent job of warning, but if you are bring in the entire play services I would recommend pulling in the pieces since that was where my incompatibilities were coming from. Here is what it looks like now:

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       android {
       compileSdkVersion 25
       buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 23
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
       }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
       compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
   }
   ```

For anyone who finds the whole support library to be confusing and a mess (why would anyone think that?) this blog was very helpful:

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/

Thanks also to Gabriele Mariotti for pointing me in the right direction. I will address the White Labeling conversion to Gradle in another question. Please chime in if I have this all incorrect...I will be the first to admit this is all very confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is : do I still need to have the upgraded versions of these libs here or is this done via a Gradle addition for running out Android Studio?

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

- Using the latest version is always a good idea
- You should avoid using the the wildcard `+` in your dependencies, because in this way you are not able to replicate the same build in different time (because it changes in the time).
- Use the same version of support libraries. The gms libraries have a dependencies with the support-v4 and you should use the same version.
- it is not a good idea to have all gms modules `(com.google.android.gms:play-services)`. You can add only the required modules.

> And if not by lib dependencies as listed, how can I have the Ant build pick these upgrades once I make them?

It is not so simple. In my opinion you should convert your ant script in gradle. It would be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried to pull out the specific packages play services modules but ran into issues identifying which ones I needed. I find the whole mechanism pretty confusing - trying to line up compile, build, target and library versions seems a bit complicated. I will update my question when I have it all working. Appreciate the help!